# Evaluate Physics equation with missing operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math.js

I am trying to evaluate physics equation using math.js library which user writes in a textbox.

For instance, its `F=ma` as there is no operator between`ma` which should be like `m*a` to evaluate how can I add missing operator in equation if any is not present in it..

```
var equation = 'f=ma';
var variables={m:7,F:35,a:5};
// separate the left and rhs of the equation
var lhs_rhs = equation.split('=');
var lhs = math.eval(equation_lhs_rhs[0],variables);
var rhs = math.eval(equation_lhs_rhs[1],variables);
if (lhs == rhs) {
  alert('Equation is fine');
}
```

Comment: You have to have some rules/restriction when a user enters an equation into the textbox. because how do you know whether `ma` is single operand or two operands which miss an operator (`+,*,/,-`) ?

Comment: First restrict user to an alphbet for a variable. Then if there is two variable together, insert * between them

Comment: In physic's equation mostly user can only miss the multiplier(*) else (+,-,/) he must need to write them.